# Log Binomial Regression: Estimate and Error = 0

Tags: regression-coefficients, standard-error

I have a log-binomial regression  of Tested (yes/no) with a sample size of about 8000. I am using two categorical predictors var1 and var2. Var1 takes on the values a, b, c, d, e. Var2 takes on the values of Type 1, Type 2, Type 3, no. I can't figure out why the estimate and standard error for 'No' is 0. I know that if the estimate is 0 (or close to 0), the term is non-significant, but I can't imagine why there would be no variation in that term. Is the model not valid? Here is my code and the output. Appreciate your help.

```
proc genmod data = DATA;
    class VAR1(ref='a') Var2(ref='Type 3')
    / PARAM=REFERENCE;
    model Tested (event='1')= VAR1 VAR2
    / dist=bin link=log type3 aggregate ;
run;
```

[image]

Comment: presumably "No" is the *reference level* for Variable 2, so there isn't an estimated parameter for it.

Comment: Sometimes it means that the parameter is completely redundant (e.g. that grouping has complete overlap with another parameter in your model, in its simplest form). Regardless, the fact that the DF (degrees of freedom) is equal to zero indicates that a parameter can't be estimated.

Comment: Re James: When you say complete overlap, do you mean it is a linear combination of another variable, or the observations in Type 3 are the same observations in another group? Because based on the variable construction, it cannot be the latter.

Comment: Re Ben: 'Type 3' is the reference level, not 'No'.

Comment: Re; James. You were right. After a little digging, Var 2 'No' is a linear combination of Var 1. Post your comment as an answer, and I'll verify it.